# Force Variable to be Stored in FLASH in C Using ARM Processor

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I know I can force an array into FLASH in ARM by declaring it "const". But this is not truly an array of consts: I want to be able to write to it regularly. I have three large arrays that take up ~50k of the 128kB of SRAM I have available, but I have an order of magnitude more FLASH than I need. How can I force these three arrays into FLASH without declaring them const? Using IAR, BTW.

Tried using the __no_init keyword; according to the linker map files this had no effect.

Comment: Context missing. "I know I can force an array into FLASH in ARM by declaring it `const`" - well, I can't, I have no Flash in my computer.

Comment: Flash memory, I take it, not Adobe/Macromedia flash?

Comment: This sounds like it would depend heavily upon what tools you are using and how they choose to implement. Writing to flash requires a particular sequence of hardware operations that goes beyond a normal memory access. So check your development tools guide for whether it supports it. If you need such support, you might have to hunt down a tool that does it.

Comment: It depends on the **Flash** technology.  There is the old **NOR** flash that allow *XIP* for **read-only** access; this is fine for *code* and *rodata* and is much the same as traditional **ROM**.  Also, there is newer SPI flash and others with built-in RAM which can read a page fast enough to support *read* bursts to some CPUs.  Typical wear cycles are 10k - 1000k for flash.  You can use wear leveling to extend this.  The answer depends on your **FLASH** technology and the product life/write frequency.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the original question, you can write a *linker script* to force any variable to reside in a predetermined area of memory (declaring them `const` does not *force* the compiler to put it in FLASH, it is merely a strong suggestion).

On the other hand, overabundance of FLASH is not in itself a good reason to keep a non-`const` array in flash. Among the reasons are: 1) depending on the chip, the access to FLASH memory can be much slower than RAM access (especially for writing) 2) FLASH can only be rewritten a limited number of times: it is not a problem for an occasional rewrite but if your code constantly rewrites FLASH memory, you can ruin it rather quicky. 3) There are special procedures to write to FLASH (ARM makes it easy but it is still not as simple as writing to RAM).

Comment: alexsh, thanks for the reply. I am attempting to benchmark the execution time for accessign the external FLASH, this is why I'm asking. But that is a good point about constant writes to FLASH; in my application the writes would be frequent so likely not a good idea.

Comment: I have not done IAR in a while but as I recall `#pragma location = "REGION_NAME"` in your code would place the array in the region `REGION_NAME`. Then, in your linker script, define REGION_NAME to be part of the FLASH memory region.

Answer (score 3):

The C language, compilers, etc are not able to generate chip/board specific flash routines.  If you wish to use flash pages to store read/write data you are going to have to have at least a page worth of ram and some read/write routines.  You would need to have very many of these variables to overcome the cost of ram and execution time needed to keep the master copy in flash.  In general every time you write the value to flash, you will need to read out the whole page, erase the page, then write back the whole page with the one item changed.  Now if you know how your flash works (Generally it is erase to ones and write zeros) you could read the prior version, compare differences and if an erase is not needed then do a write of that one item.

if you dont have dozens of variables you wish to do this with then, dont bother.  You would want to declare a const something offset for each variable in this flash and have a read/write routine

```
const unsigned int off_items=0x000;
const unsigned int off_dollars=0x004;
...

unsigned int flash_read_nv ( unsigned int offset );
void flash_write_nv ( unsigned int offset, unsigned int data);
```

so this code that uses .data:

```
items++;
dollars=items*5;
```

Using your desire to keep the variables in flash becomes:

```
unsigned int ra,rb;

ra= flash_read_nv(off_items);
rb= flash_read_nv(off_dollars);
ra++;
rb=ra*5;
flash_write_nv(off_items,ra);
flash_write_nv(off_dollars,ra);
```

And of course the flash writes take hundreds to thousands of clock cycles or more to execute.  Plus require 64, 128, or 256 bytes of ram (or more) depending on the flash page size.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, this page is the best thing that pops up when looking how to store data in flash with the AVR ARM compiler.

On page 359 of the manual (the one that comes with v7.50 of the compiler), does show this as a way to put data in flash:

```
#define FLASH _Pragma("location=\"FLASH\"")
```

On page 332 of the manual, however, it says this:

> "Static and global objects declared const are allocated in ROM."

I tested it and it seems the pragma is unnecessary with the IAR compiler, as specifying const puts it in flash already (as stated in the original question).

From the other answers, it seems like the OP didn't really want to use flash.  If anyone like me comes to this page to figure out how to store data in flash with the AVR ARM compiler, however, I hope my answer saves them some time.

Answer (score 1):

In IAR, you can declare your array as follows:

`__root __no_init const uint8_t myVect[50000] @0x12345678`

Where, of course, 0x12345678 is the address in FLASH.